# Creating Elastic Beanstalk environment with new application with Java Sample Application using AWS Cloud Formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I'm a bit stuck with this one. I managed to create an elastic beanstalk environment with my own Cloud Formation template, but I can only launch it for an existing application. How can I use the same resource (AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment) to also create a new application and how do I deploy the standard AWS Java Sample Application to this new environment using the same template.

If I use this:

```
Resources:
  MyEB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: customerApp
```

there will be an error saying that `customerApp` does not exist.

As per Marcin's request, my full template with values removed to make it shorter if that makes sense:

```
Resources:
  MyEB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: customerApp
      Description: Test
      PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-1::platform/Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.2.17
      EnvironmentName: iw-test3
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: ImageId

        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: DisableIMDSv1

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: username

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: password

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: rest_client_id

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
          OptionName: rest_client_secret

        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: VPCId      

        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: Subnets

        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: ELBSubnets

        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:loadbalancer
          OptionName: SharedLoadBalancer 
        
        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
          OptionName: Rules   

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default
          OptionName: HealthCheckPath
          Value: /health

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions
          OptionName: ManagedActionsEnabled
          Value: true

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions
          OptionName: PreferredStartTime

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions:platformupdate
          OptionName: UpdateLevel

        - Namespace: aws:ec2:instances
          OptionName: InstanceTypes
    
        - Namespace: aws:ec2:instances
          OptionName: SupportedArchitectures

        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
          OptionName: MaxSize

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy
          OptionName: ProxyServer

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: ServiceRole

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: LoadBalancerIsShared

        - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
          OptionName: LoadBalancerType

        - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
          OptionName: AssociatePublicIpAddress

        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile     

        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listenerrule:dnsRule
          OptionName: PathPatterns
       
        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listenerrule:dnsRule
          OptionName: Priority        

        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listenerrule:dnsRule
          OptionName: Process
      
        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listenerrule:dnsRule
          OptionName: HostHeaders
```

**update**

I added the below resources:

```
MyApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: Test Application 
  MyApplicationVarsion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: customerApp_IW
      Description: Test Application Version
      SourceBundle: 
        S3Bucket: !Sub "elasticbeanstalk-samples-${AWS::Region}"
        S3Key: corretto.zip
```

And the error am getting now is this:

```
Unable to download from S3 location (Bucket: elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1 Key: corretto.zip). Reason: Forbidden: S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1, S3Key=corretto.zip (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 8abc30ac-fd88-4828-95bd-67e3ed69aebe; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: What is your complete template and full error message?

Comment: Full error is `No Application named 'customerApp' found. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: some id; Proxy: null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your own [AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-version.html). Then you define [VersionLabel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-versionlabel) to deploy your specific zip.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've added some resources. But am getting another error now. I can't get the correto.zip sample app from AWS S3 bucket. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: I sorted it out, thanks. I used S3Key: php-newsample-app.zip to see at least if my template does the job, and it did. I just need to find out how I can use a corretto sample app, not php.

Comment: I got it: `java-sample-app.zip`